# CoreData UITableViewController. Visible rows populated, blank after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I'm still learning objective C and I've got a bit of a strange problem with my **UITableViewController**. It is being populated by CoreData and I am using the [CoreDataTableViewController](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall) class from Stanford University.

When the app first loads, the table looks as though it is being populated as all visible rows are showing the data. The table has the correct number of rows matching the number of rows in Core Data, but when I scroll the table view, the cells beneath are blank, then if I scroll back up to the top of the table view, the original cells, that were populated are blank as well. I'm not what is working as it is showing some data initially..

Thanks

This is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InfoCell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  UserAccount *account = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
  UILabel *descriptionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];

  titleLabel.text = account.title;
  descriptionLabel.text = account.detail;

  return cell;
}
```

My viewWillAppear calls this function:

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{

  NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UserAccount"];

  request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title"
                                                                                   ascending:YES
                                                                                    selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
  _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                  managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext
                                                                    sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                             cacheName:nil];
  [self performFetch];
}
```

Comment: So the table view seems to contain all the cells, it's just that they're all blank?

Comment: Correct. It has 78 cells, and the first ones that appear (before scrolling) are populated correctly.

Comment: Can you check if `titleLabel.text`, `descriptionLabel.text`, `account.title` and `account.detail` aren't nil?

Comment: In the `UITableViewCell` `prepareForReuse` method, are you making any changes to the cell? If so, show the `prepareForReuse` method.

Comment: `titleLabel.text`, `descriptionLabel.text`, `account.title` and `account.detail` are populated for the first rows, as I scroll they all become nil (even when I scroll back to the top of the table).

Comment: I'm not using the `prepareForReuse` method

Comment: @Dave hey have you get solution for this, i found it`s happen due to core-data "data <fault>" technique. Please update your answer if you get solution.